# How to get all visible points in the map view bounds in Azure Maps

Tags: javascript, points, point-in-polygon, azure-maps

I've been searching and trying to use a sample of the select point within a polygon example however I am not drawing a new polygon but rather one is already in the map to use as selection boundary. I have many points on the map as well but some are out of view or possibly hidden due to zoom ratio so I w/ant to ignore all those points from being selected even if they are in the selection polygon. Is this possible?

```
// searchArea is populated by click method
    function searchPolygon(searchArea) {
        var visiblePointsOnly = ???;
        var poly = searchArea.toJson(); // This is failing saying toJson not a function?

        // Calculate all points that are within the polygon area.
        var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(visiblePointsOnly, poly);

        return ptsWithin;
    }
```

TIA!
Rick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out...might not be the best but it does what I need it to do!

```
function searchPolygon(searchArea) {
    // Get points visible on map
    var points = pointLayer.getSource();

    if(points){
        var poly = searchArea.shapes[0].toJson();
        points = points.shapes[0].toJson();

        // Calculate all points that are within the polygon area.
        var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, poly);
    }

    return ptsWithin;
}
```

Hopefully this will help others needing the same functionality,
Cheers!
Rick...