# Remove/Hide/Delete an array of features from Azure Map

Tags: javascript, azure-maps

This is a follow on questions from [Azure Maps (with Turf.js) - can't get the 'points' from the SymbolLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674558/azure-maps-with-turf-js-cant-get-the-points-from-the-symbollayer)

I now have a function that loads the data "onclick" from a JSON location.

What I am trying to do is now Remove the data. A toggle-on / toggle-off function.

Full code is: https://espiritos.projectwebdev.co.uk/index-v1.0.8a.html

But the key function I am concerned with is:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".toggleCounty.on", function(event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("on")) {
    var elementsToRemove = "";
    $(this).toggleClass("off");
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    var countyID = $(this).attr("data-countyID");

    var url = geoJsonData[countyID].url;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var noOfFeatures = Object.keys(data.features).length;
      console.log(noOfFeatures);
      for (var i = 0; i < noOfFeatures; i++) {
        console.log("[" + i + "]");
        console.log(data.features[i]);
        datasource.remove(data.features[i]);
        // map.data.remove(data.features[i]);
        debugger;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I do an API lookup from a variable "geoJsonData":

```js
var geoJsonData = [
  {
    name: "Hertfordshire",
    shown: "off",
    url:
      "https://www.naptan.projectwebdev.co.uk/api/v1/get/stoppoints?fields=all&format=geojson&filter=NptgLocalityRef|E0000708",
    geomType: "points"
  },
  {
    name: "Hampshire",
    shown: "off",
    url:
      "https://www.naptan.projectwebdev.co.uk/api/v1/get/stoppoints?fields=all&format=geojson&filter=NptgLocalityRef|E0044074",
    geomType: "points"
  },
  {
    name: "Oxfordshire",
    shown: "off",
    url:
      "https://www.naptan.projectwebdev.co.uk/api/v1/get/stoppoints?fields=all&format=geojson&filter=NptgLocalityRef|E0000708",
    geomType: "points"
  }
];
```

I load in the "features" from the JSON...

And then I just can't work out how to remove those features from the map.

I have popped a "debugger;" where the issue is.

I am extremely grateful for any guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the first code block you are loading GeoJSON data from the web and then trying to remove it from a data source, but you never add it to the data source. That won't work. If you previously loaded the same data into the data source, I don't think that would work either since these are fundamentally different JSON object instances. The one way you can get this to work is to add unique ID's to each feature in your GeoJSON files. Then the data source can do a match on that. For example:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": 1,
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-0.61827807482, 51.537852954]
  },
  "properties": {
    "AtcoCode": "040000000127",
    "NaptanCode": "bucgjtjt",
    "CommonName": "Farnham House",
    "Street": "Farnham Lane",
    "Indicator": "adj",
    "NptgLocalityRef": "E0044074",
    "GridType": "UKOS",
    "Easting": "495927",
    "Northing": "183010",
    "StopType": "BCT",
    "BusStopType": "MKD",
    "TimingStatus": "OTH",
    "CompassPoint": "SE",
    "Degrees": "135",
    "StopAreaRef": "",
    "AdministrativeAreaRef": "70"
    }
},
```

Note you will need to make sure all id's across all your files are unique.

Some other approaches you can consider;

- If there is a property in each feature that can relate a feature back to its original file (i.e. "source": "Hertfordshire"), then you could us a filter in the layers to control what is rendered based on this property.
- If you only ever load the data for one file at a time and remove all other data, then consider using the `datasource.setShapes` function. This will overwrite all data in the data source.

**Update**

I have put together a more in depth sample that shows toggling between different data sets. It looks like these data sets are small, so I load them the first time they are needed into the data source and leave them in there. Then to toggle I simply use a filter at the layer level. This makes it much faster to reload a data set a second time. This will work fine for data sets that are tens of thousands in size. If you are working with larger data sets, then removing the data might be something to consider. I also noticed when putting this sample together, the URL for the first and last data set you provided are the same (assuming this is an error).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map, datasource, layer;

        var geoJsonData = [
          {
            name: "Hertfordshire",
            shown: "off",
            url:
              "https://www.naptan.projectwebdev.co.uk/api/v1/get/stoppoints?fields=all&format=geojson&filter=NptgLocalityRef|E0000708",
            geomType: "points"
          },
          {
            name: "Hampshire",
            shown: "off",
            url:
              "https://www.naptan.projectwebdev.co.uk/api/v1/get/stoppoints?fields=all&format=geojson&filter=NptgLocalityRef|E0044074",
            geomType: "points"
          },
          {
            name: "Oxfordshire",
            shown: "off",
            url:
              "https://www.naptan.projectwebdev.co.uk/api/v1/get/stoppoints?fields=all&format=geojson&filter=NptgLocalityRef|E0000708",
            geomType: "points"
          }
        ];

        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: [-0.76, 51.6],
                zoom: 10,
                view: 'Auto',

                //Add your Azure Maps key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '<Your Azure Maps Key>'
                }
            });

            //Wait until the map resources are ready.
            map.events.add('ready', function () {

                //Create a data source and add it to the map.
                datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                map.sources.add(datasource);

                //Create a layer to render the points.
                layer = new atlas.layer.BubbleLayer(datasource);
                map.layers.add(layer);
                
                loadDataSetPanel();
            });
        }

        function loadDataSetPanel(){
            var html = [];
            
            for(var i=0;i<geoJsonData.length;i++){
                html.push(`<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleDataSet('${geoJsonData[i].name}')"> ${geoJsonData[i].name}<br/>`);         
            }
            
            document.getElementById('dataSetPanel').innerHTML = html.join('');
        }
        
        function toggleDataSet(name){
            var ds = getDataSetByName(name);
            
            if(ds){
                //Toggle the shown state of the data set.
                ds.show = (typeof ds.show === undefined)? true : !ds.show;
                
                //Update filter on data source.
                updateFilter();
                
                //Check to see if data set is loaded, if not, load it.
                if(!ds.loaded){
                    loadDataSet(ds);
                }
            }
        }
        
        function loadDataSet(ds) {
            //Fetch the data directly as we want to modify it before it is entered into the data source.
            fetch(ds.url)
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(r => {
                    var f = r.features;
                    
                    //Enrich the features.
                    for(var i=0;i<f.length;i++){
                        //Make the AtcoCode the unique ID for each feature. This will allow for lookups and removal by ID.
                        f[i].id = f[i].properties.AtcoCode;
                        
                        //Add the data set name as a property for each feature for filtering purposes.              
                        f[i].properties.dataset = ds.name;
                    }
                    
                    //Add the features to the data source.
                    datasource.add(f);
                });     
        }
        
        function updateFilter(){
            var dataSetsToShow = [];
            
            //Get the name of each data set that should be shown.
            for(var i=0;i<geoJsonData.length;i++){
                if(geoJsonData[i].show){
                    dataSetsToShow.push(geoJsonData[i].name);
                }           
            }
            
            if(dataSetsToShow.length === 0){
                //If there is no layers to show, set filter to false. 
                layer.setOptions({ filter: ['literal', false] });
            } else {
                //Create a data driven filter to hide the 
                var filter = [
                    'match',
                    
                    //Get the data set property.
                    ['get', 'dataset'],
                    
                    //See if it matches any of the data set names to show.
                    dataSetsToShow,
                    
                    //If so, return true, to indicate the feature should be shown.
                    true,
                    
                    //Else, return false to not render feature.
                    false
                ];
                
                //Update the filter on the layer. 
                layer.setOptions({ filter: filter });
            }
        }
        
        function getDataSetByName(name){
            for(var i=0;i<geoJsonData.length;i++){
                if(geoJsonData[i].name === name){
                    return geoJsonData[i];
                }           
            }
            
            return null;
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;     
        }
    
        #myMap {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #dataSetPanel {
             position: absolute;
            left:10px;
            top:10px;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap"></div>
    
    <div id="dataSetPanel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am loading the data in using datasource.importDataFromUrl(geoJsonFeed.url)

Full code is: https://espiritos.projectwebdev.co.uk/index-v1.0.8a.html

Yes... each file will have a name: e.g. Herfordsire. AND each point has a unique id which is the "AtcoCode".

I am really hoping you can extend your answer with that additional info. 

In much hope.

Comment: If you only plan on having a few data sets, then it might be easier to have a separate data source for each data set. If you plan on there being a lot 10+ in the future, then using a single data source and some filters would likely be better. I'll see about pulling together a sample.